# Print custom field group from multiple records

Tags: custom-fields, civireport, tokens, pdf, admin

Currently we have a **group of custom fields** "Date" and "Medical Note" that are displayed in the table tab and that **allow multiple records**.
[image]
[image]

We need **all these fields to be printable in a PDF document** and also other basic contact fields (Name, date of birth). We were thinking of doing this with *"Tokens"* in a **custom template**, however we were unable to add "Tokens" to the custom fields that allow multiple registrations.
[image]

**Is there any option or plugin to print all these custom fields (multiple records) in a single custom PDF document?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you could build a Search kit with the same table and use [Searchkit token](https://civicrm.org/extensions/searchkit-tokens) extension

Comment: Already installed the extension to generate the Tokens. My question is. Do I have to search for Contacts or Custom Fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a SearchKit search for these fields (multiple-record custom fields are treated as their own searchable entity in SearchKit), then click on "Download Spreadsheet" and choose the PDF format.

Comment: Printing multiple record fields only prints the last record and not all the records.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Depending on how you configure the search you certainly can print multiple and not just the last one. By default SearchKit will return all records & the Export action will print all records.